# Align slideToggle boxes to bottom of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment, slidetoggle

I have the follwing so far: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjxii/59RsP/1/)

Just a small script that pops out list elements

```
$(function() {
  $("li.content").hide();
  $("ul.nav").delegate("li.toggle", "click", function() { 
      $(this).next().slideToggle("fast").siblings(".content").slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

I am trying to figure out how I can align the box that slides out when you click "about" to the bottom of the outer div as it is with the "contact" box. Contact should also stay pinned to the bottom as well.

Can I achieve this without having to modify the javascript purely by changing the css, or do I have to make different toggle functions for both boxes?

Thank you all, much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah you can do this with just CSS. It's actually already applying styling from you.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this to your `.content`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/eeqBk/)

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This way, the boxes just slide out while the surrounding div doesn't change height. The way I'd like to have it is for the top to stay positioned below it's toggling list element but still align to the bottom. Like the contact box does.

I have already tried making 2 classes for the contact and about box, where the about box has a negative margin. but that would not be very elegant I suppose?

Comment: I think that's your only option.

Comment: Use the standard format for links. [](). And hey! You got it working. What did you change?

Comment: check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjxii/59RsP/2/). I have added
`.about {
    margin-bottom: -19px;
}`
as a class.
It works, but I would love to be able to come up with something more smooth (seeing as the animation is kind of choppy as well with this additional class as opposed to the 'contact' animation.)

Comment: The animation looks fine to me. And you REALLY need to start including links correctly. Don't use HTML. Instead use [text](url).

Comment: No problem. Here is a link on [How to Ask Good Questions!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I give it to all the newbies.